# Simulate typing input into Java Program using Python

Tags: java, python, linux, unix, stdin

I'm writing a Python script to grade ~300 assignments which take input using a Scanner(System.in)

What I thought I could do was something as simple as calling:

```
    os.system("cat input.txt | java {} > program_output.txt".format(class_file))
```

I've also tried

```
    os.system("java {} < input.txt > program_output.txt".format(class_file))
```

However, on some assignments, even though it works perfectly when the inputs are typed by hand, when it's getting the inputs from this input.txt file, the program is giving me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

This is after two previous calls to console.next(), and the error is happening on a call to console.nextLine()

I have no idea why this is happening, but it wouldn't be very simple to modify everyone's code, so I was wondering if there was a way to simulate the actual typing of the inputs using python, instead of redirecting stdin. Thank you!

EDIT: For the record, the reason the Java program couldn't accept piping from stdin is because the programs created more than one scanner, instead of passing around a scanner.

Comment: Don't give up on redirecting stdin. That's definitely the best way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at Jython, is a java implementation of python that can import java classes natively.

Comment: did you try executing the same using subprocess?

Comment: @themistoklik I tried literally typing out that command in the shell, and it gave my error.

Comment: @JohnKugelman How do you suggest I change what I'm doing?

Comment: What if you readlines and for first line you do what you're doing, but for every other line you just `os.system(line)`?

Comment: @themistoklik Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Arya By hand you're providing line by line input, so my idea was how that is simulated with python. So for a file containing inputs a,b,c,d I'd try reading the file in python so I end up with a list `lines = [a,b,c,d]`. Then I'd do a `os.system("java {} < input.txt > program_output.txt".format(line[0]))` followed by `for line in lines[1:]:
                        os.system(line)`

Comment: I don't think the next os.system would run until the Java program had terminated.

Comment: Let's take a look at that "No line found" error. Create a [mcve] with a tiny Java program, Python program, and sample `input.txt` that doesn't work and let's figure out why.

Comment: I think the reason was because of two scanner objects being created by some students, however my question wasn't "How do I debug this issue," it was "how can I simulate typing"

Answer (score 1):

The best way to simulate actual human input would be [pexpect python module](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is based on expect Linux utility and which in its turn made precisely for the purpose of handling interactive tools.

(I will try to provide example once reach my desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your input.txt file contains enough newline characters? Namely as many as 'enters' needed when doing the input by hand.

To do this in python try using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess

with open('input.txt') as f:
l=f.readlines()

l=map(lambda x:x.strip(), l) #no newlines we don't want

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python script.py'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

s = proc.communicate(input='\n'.join(l))
```

Where script.py is a simple script similar to your java, expecting input line by line

**script.py**:

```
print "input:"
raw_input()
print 1
raw_input()
print 2
print "done!"
```

This simulates sending each element of the list along with an enter in the shell . Printing s, we get back a tuple (stdout,stderr) ,so doing `s[0]` will get you your java results back.

Please note that you have to supply no less than the lines expected by the java program, and if this works, redirecting stdin should work as well.

Comment: What's the problem with `< input.txt`, and why would this fix it? Seems to me this would have the same problem.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I see no problem with it, however the title of the question asks for a python solution simulating input. I personally prefer redirecting stdin. I now suspect that his input.txt does not have enough `\n` characters. Python complains as well with an EOFError.

Comment: The problem I realized was that the Java program had multiple scanners, and there was a race condition when I piped from input.

Comment: I wrote an AppleScript script to type the commands whenever my python program needed me to, I just had to press play 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, my solution was to make an AppleScript program, and then have my program call the AppleScript program:

```
activate application "Terminal"

tell application "Terminal"

activate


delay 0.2

tell application "System Events"

keystroke "C"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "madlib.txt"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "madlib_output.txt"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "jeopardy"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "200"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "dollars"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "tallest"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "moutain"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "The United States of America"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "V"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "madlib_output.txt"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

keystroke "Q"

delay 0.2

keystroke return

end tell

end tell
```